# Is mysql compatible with sql-92?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

The other day I was trying to create a table in mysql usign a standard syntax:

```
create table client(
    rc character varying(11)
    constraint client_pk primary key 
);
```

However, mysql doesn't support setting a primary key this way. (I'm 99% sure it's compliant with the sql-92 norm)
So my question: Does MySQL fail to support at even these basic things from a 20 year old standard, or am I missing something?

EDIT: my goal is NOT to create this table using using some mysql dialect, but to create this table using a standardized syntax. And the question is whether it is possible.

Comment: I beg to differ :) of course you have to specify to which field(s) you set the primary key, but since I did NOT write comma after the rc field, the constraint should automatically apply to this field

Comment: Ah, sorry. Didn't notice that. MySQL does not support this (and even if it did: you can't specify the name for a primary key constraint anyway)

Comment: MySQL recognizes only a subset of the SQL-92 standard syntax; and of the subset it does accept, some of that syntax can result in behavior that is *not* compliant with the SQL-92 specification. So, MySQL is somewhat compatible, but it is also non-compliant in several key areas. An entire section of the documentation is devoted to these key "differences", and this depends on the version of MySQL. For MySQL 5.5, see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/compatibility.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your question, no, MySQL is not fully compliant with the SQL-92 specification, in that MySQL supports only a subset of the specification, and MySQL has some significant(ly useful) extensions which are not part of the SQL-92 specification.

This is not just about the SQL syntax that MySQL accepts and recognizes, but (the probably bigger issue) is about what MySQL actually *does* with the syntax, the actual operations that MySQL performs with the syntax that it does accept. That's really a more important issue than the more superficial issue of what syntax MySQL recognizes.

It's not that MySQL is lazy. And it's not that MySQL just doesn't care.

There is an entire section of the MySQL documentation devoted to MySQL differences from the SQL standard.  And the most important differences aren't really about syntax, but rather about that fact that "MySQL performs operations differently in some cases."

For example, MySQL accepts syntax for CHECK constraints, but MySQL does not actually do any checking or make any attempt to enforce CHECK constraints. MySQL accepts syntax that meets the SQL-92 specification, but the behavior of MySQL is much different from other databases that accept that same syntax.

As another example, the behavior of MySQL with respect to FOREIGN KEY constraints differs significantly, depending on whether the storage engine for the table is MyISAM or InnoDB.

---

To get your CREATE TABLE statement to execute in MySQL, you would need to change it.

It looks like the easiest option for you would be to remove `constraint client_pk` from the sql text. You can either specify the table constraint in the column definition:

```
create table client(
   rc character varying(11) primary key 
);
```

or declare the table constraint separately"

```
create table client(
   rc character varying(11),
   primary key (rc)
);
```

Both of those forms are entirely compatible with the SQL-92 specification.

Note that MySQL does accept the syntax for constraint name definition, when the declaration of the constraint is not on the column, e.g.

```
create table client(
   rc character varying(11),
   constraint client_pk primary key (rc)
);
```

And that syntax is also entirely compatible with SQL-92 specifiction.

But note that MySQL *ignores* the supplied constraint name, and assigns the name `PRIMARY` to the primary key constraint. And this is true even if the constraint is declared in a separate ALTER TABLE statement.

Note that the syntax that MySQL accepts, and in some cases the operations it performs, is dependent on the settings of specific MySQL variables, in particular, `sql_mode`, and of particular concern, in the case of your statement, the setting of the `default-storage-engine` variable, and whether this table will be created using the `MyISAM` engine or the `InnoDB` engine, or even the corner case that default-storage-engine has been set to `BLACKHOLE`.

I understand that your goal is to "create this table with standardized syntax".

But I think you really *DO* need to be concerned with at least some minimum subset of MySQL specific syntax, in as far as the variety of possible behaviors that MySQL can exhibit when presented with "standardized syntax". Consider:

```
SET default-storage-engine = 'MyISAM' ;
SET default-storage-engine = 'InnoDB' ;
SET sql_mode = '' ; 
SET sql_mode = 'ANSI' ;
```

Comment: This is funny. So there is a great difference what MySQL ACCEPTS and what SUPPORTS(in the way we want it). One question: why doesn't MySQL support some of these very important integrity parameters (like you mentioned CHECK, or ON CASCADE DELETE,...)? I mean is that rather flaw(something that might appear in the future), or a feature  of some (weird) kind?

Comment: @Novellizator: These differences are not a flaw or defect in the MySQL implementation; rather, these differences are a result of MySQL meeting it's specified design goals. Older versions of MySQL didn't accept some "standard" syntax, which presented difficulty for users attempting to "import" definitions exported from other DBMS (e.g. Oracle.)  And I think the "import a schema from foreign database" issue was one of the main drivers for newer version of MySQL accepting additional syntax that it will basically ignore. MySQL is leaving the door open for future implementation...

Answer (score 2):

This works for me in MySQL 5.5.29:

```
create table client(
    rc character varying(11),
    constraint client_pk primary key(rc)
);
```

However, as a_horse_with_no_name has pointed out, MySQL ignores the `client_pk` name and calls it `PRIMARY`.

References:

http://savage.net.au/SQL/sql-92.bnf.html

http://owen.sj.ca.us/~rk/howto/sql92.html

Comment: You don't need a column `client_pk`. That should be the name of the constraint. The syntax *is* SQL-92 compliant, it's a column level constraint: http://savage.net.au/SQL/sql-92.bnf.html#column%20definition

Comment: Ah. Thank you for pointing that out @a_horse_with_no_name. I regularly work with different databases (DB2 and MySQL) so I've been working on using valid SQL-92 syntax to execute SQL against either database. However we never use "raw" SQL statements like this to create tables on either system, they always get created in other ways so I'm just not familiar with CREATE syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table tablename
(
    column_Name varchar(20) not null,
    column_Name varchar(20),
    primary key(column_name)
);
```

In this way you can create table and set primary key.